# top 2 results on group by statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table "record: id,name,score" and **would like to query for the 2 highest scores per each name**. I am using group by to get the highest score as :

```
select name,max(score)as score from record group by name order by score
```

But I think its not possible to get the 2 highest scores using group by, how do I get them ?

Comment: mysql .. as in the question tags

Comment: do wanna in Array....???

Comment: You are correct, this is not a GROUP BY problem.  See my answer, below.

Comment: output can be anything, as long as it contains every name in table with  2 top scores for that name

Comment: Very similar problem solved already; see [mysql: Using LIMIT within GROUP BY to get N results per group?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/mysql-using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a ranking function which MySQL does not natively support at the moment. However, you can simulate it like so:

```
Select name, score, rnk
From  (
      Select name, score
        , @curRank := if(@name=name, if(@score=score, @curRank, @curRank + 1), 1) As rnk
        , @name := name
        , @score := score
      From  (
            Select name, score
            From record
              Cross Join ( Select @curRank := 0, @name := '', @score := -1 ) As Z1
            Order By name, score Desc
            ) as R
      ) As Z
Where rnk <= 2
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/04d26/17)

Answer (score 4):

```
 SELECT name, score FROM record R1
   WHERE (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT score) FROM record R2
          WHERE R2.name = R1.name 
            AND R2.score >= R1.score) <= 2
```

Not especially performant (that is, may be kind of slow), but it should return what you're looking for.

Comment: This is getting closer, (though substatement needs to be R2), but if the 2 highest scores for a person are the same score, only 1 is added to the result.

Comment: Yes, just noticed that.  Hold on. . .

Comment: Okay, should handle ties in the second highest score per user now. . .

Comment: The first `DISTINCT` is still going to limit you to one row if the top 2 scores tie.

Comment: Oops, meant to *move* the DISTINCT, not just add a second one. . .

Comment: Edited to final version.  There is a issue of definition here, however — if the user's scores are 10, 10, 9, 8 are the "top two scores" for that user 10 and 10 or 10 and 9?  Current query returns 10 and 9.  To get 10 and 10, change `COUNT(DISTINCT Score)` to `COUNT(Score)`.  That version would return 10 and 10, but it would have trouble with scores 10, 9, 9, 8 when it would return only 10.

Comment: Well, it should return 10,10 in the first example and 10,9 in the second example. I always try to do as much as possible in sql, would it be better to push it to the programming side and do:

foreach name in table records
-> get top 2 scores 
? it is the east way to deal with this, but probably less performant.

Comment: I also like to do everything I can in SQL (then encapsulate the logic in a VIEW for DRY purposes).  I'm sure you can get what you want out of SQL, although the performance may fall off a bit.  It might be easier to do if you have a unique ID or DateTime identifier on those `record` records.  Do you?

Comment: "record: id,name,score" -> id is auto increment int PK.

Comment: I'm working kind of quickly, but I think this version will do it for you.  If not, I'll circle back later in the day.

Comment: this actually returns the entire table content, i appreciate your time input btw!

Answer (score 0):

`select TOP (2) name,max(score)as score from record group by name order by score`

EDIT:
I just noticed its in `mysql` then

`select name,max(score)as score from record group by name order by score LIMIT 2`

Comment: No, this is high scores for the two highest scoring players.  Sdry wants two scores returned *per player* and they should be the two highest for *that player*.

Comment: ops, seems the question was vague to me then

Comment: Come on ppl! there were at lest 4 answers say the same thing my post do, all removed but still mine here! and plus I got downvoting for something that I understand it wrong! this isn't fair!

Comment: I thought it was pretty clear (at least, the part in bold).  But I think it's not very kind to rate down this answer, which is a genuine attempt to help.

Comment: Rami is right, a lot of people asnwered wrong and deleted once they realized. I added the bold after all the wrong answers, but did not modify text.